# ASP.NET Caching and AJAX Calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, azure, azure-sql-database

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC3 project, i am using Ajax jquery to communicate with my controllers. i use asp.net caching to store the results before updating the database (SQL Azure).

```
        function SaveCustomersList() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Customers/SaveCustomersList/',
            data: "",
            cache: false,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

The application work fine but not for all users !!

When some users try to update the database the content passed to my DAL objects is null.

this is just happening with the users working on a network.

i have no explanation for that.

thanks for your help.

Comment: What kind of caching are you using? ASP.NET's InProc cache or a distributed cache (e.g. stored in SQL Azure or Table Storage)? Because if you have multiple instances, the cache needs to be shared between them.

Comment: I am using InProc cache mode. Is the proxy who cause the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of questions you need to answer to get proper help:

1. How many instances of your application is running?
2. Where this application is running and local network or hosted outside?
3. When you say "users working on a network", what do u mean? Does it mean this application is accessible to users within your network or outside network?
4. If this application is running in your network, and the communication between Ajax calls and controller is passing through proxy, only then Proxy could be a factor.

As you are using InProc cache the problem It is critical to know if you have multiple instances of this application. You need to understand that the communication between your Ajax and controller is instance specific and if you have local cache to handle it that will work with only one instance. However if you have multiple instance of the same application and using local cache will not work properly because there is no guarantee that connection  X served by instance #1 will always be server by instance #1.

If you decided to run application on multiple instance, using distribured cache (i.e. Outside your instance) is the only choice you have comparative to internal (i.e. Insides your instance ASP.NET inproc) Cache.

[Added]
Here is a .net sample application to use Windows Azure Cache:
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/

If you wish to use MemCache you can use @smarx solution as described below: 
http://blog.smarx.com/posts/memcached-in-windows-azure

Comment: The probleme was the proxy the client disabled the cache on the proxy and the application worked fine.

1 - Today there is one instance but the client provides to deploy multiple instances.
2 - The application is runing on windows azure
3 - The application is accessible for all users
4 - Yes the ajax calls are passing through a proxy

How to uses distributed cache for an application running on multiple instances ?

Comment: I am glad you problem is resolved. I have edited my response to use Windows Azure Cache.

Comment: thank you. is there a way to work in distributed cache without Azure caching

Comment: The concept of distributed cache is to use an entity outside your instances and for that reason, you can use Azure Storage, SQL Azure, or a 3rd party service. Or you can use Memchache solution to integrate in your applicaton.But when to try to  build your own solution to use any of these entities, the cost to build and maintain such code could be higher and finally the speed is main factor. Windows Azure Cache would be the close to fastest available so paying a little will not hurt as you get easier and faster way to achieve your objective and you actually pay for that.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set up a distributed cache that allows you to cache data between multiple instances. You can use Azure Caching for this (but it is expensive!).

Setting the caching up is fairly easy, just follow this guide: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/cache/